# parse credentials from PHP configuration file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression, php

I'd like to write bash script to parse data from a configuration file. I searched for this but without finding something I could modify to suit my needs.

Joomla! config file:

```
   public $access = '1';
   public $debug = '0';
   public $debug_lang = '0';
   public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
   public $host = 'localhost';
   public $user = 'template';
   public $password = 'template';
   public $db = 'template_druha';
   public $dbprefix = 'dsf1i_';
   public $live_site = '';
   public $secret = '2w9gHzPb4HfAs2Y9';
   public $gzip = '0';
   public $error_reporting = 'default';
```

I'd like to parse the database credentials on lines with `"$user"` and `"$password"` and store them in a variable. What is the best practice?

Comment: If your file is PHP, use PHP (or a PHP AST parser).

Comment: Parse the file using awk to extract the $user and $password values from this joomla config file.

Comment: Have php read in and parse the file, then have print statements to return the values you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you could do:

```
user=$(grep -oP "\\\$user.+?'\K[^']+" file)
pass=$(grep -oP "\\\$password.+?'\K[^']+" file)
```

The `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, which give us `\K` (ignore anything matched so far). The `-o` means "only print the matching portion of the line. Then, we search for `$var` (we need three `\`, to avoid expanding the variable and to avoid the `$` being taken as part of the regex), a single quote and one or more non-`'` characters until the next `'`.

Alternatively, you could use `awk`:

```
user=$(awk -F"'" '/\$user/{print $2}' file)
pass=$(awk -F"'" '/\$password/{print $2}' file)
```

Here, we are setting the field delimiter to `'`, so the value of the variable will be the second field. The `awk` command prints the second field of matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample input:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
public $access = '1';
public $debug = '0';
public $debug_lang = '0';
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'template-user';
public $password = 'template-pass';
public $db = 'template_druha';
public $dbprefix = 'dsf1i_';
public $live_site = '';
public $secret = '2w9gHzPb4HfAs2Y9';
public $gzip = '0';
public $error_reporting = 'default';
```

You could do:

```
user="$(grep '$user' /tmp/foo | sed -e 's/  *$//g' -e 's/;$//' | awk -F= '{ print $2}')"
pass="$(grep '$password' /tmp/foo | sed -e 's/  *$//g' -e 's/;$//' | awk -F= '{ print $2}')"
```

- The grep searchs for the user or password lines in the given file
- The first sed expression removes any trailing whitespace
- The second sed expression removes the trailing ;
- The awk uses = as the column delimiter, and prints the second column
- The `var=$(...)` evaluates all that, takes it output and stores it in the variable

Answer (score 1):

Since this file is a PHP file, the most reliable way to extract data for it is to parse it with PHP. If you need to use the data in a shell script, write some PHP code that prints out variable assignments in shell syntax.

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "$(php -r '
    include $argv[1];
    $config = new JConfig();
    echo "joomla_user=\x27" . preg_replace("/\x27/", "\x27\\\x27\x27", $config->user) . "\x27\n";
    echo "joomla_password=\x27" . preg_replace("/\x27/", "\x27\\\x27\x27", $config->password) . "\x27\n";
' /path/to/configuration.php)"
echo "User is $joomla_user"
```